# Add multispectral raster data to a mosaic dataset

Tags: arcmap, mosaic, mosaic-dataset

I have MS images (G, R, RedEdge, NIR) and want to add them to a mosaic dataset. When creating the mosaic dataset, I cannot find an appropriate 'product definition' for it. I tried manually adding bands and wavelengths but end up with a reflectance map with two bands.

I also tried selecting 'Landsat MSS' as product definition and followed and tried to find my way by using a [tutorial](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/pdf/raster-tutorial.pdf) with the example for Landsat 7 ETM+ but it is clearly not suitable for my case.

I hope my mission is defined clearly :)